# Only allow characters that follow exact regex pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am new to regex and have a question. I am validating a date/time text input and only want to allow characters that fit an exact pattern. This is the format:

> Mar 19, 2014 at 2:00am

Obviously the date (in this case "19") and the hour (in this case "2") could be one or two characters long. On Javascript keyup, I need a regex expression that removes all characters that do not exactly fit this pattern. How can I do this with regex? This is the exact pattern:

- 3 alphabetical characters
- then a space
- then a 1 or 2 diget number
- then a coma followed by another space
- then a four digit number
- then another space
- then the word "at" followed by another space
- then a 1 or 2 digit number
- then a colon.
- then a 2 digit number
- then either the word "am" or "pm"

I do not care that it is a valid date. I simply need the entered text to fit this format.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea, since this would obstruct normal editing operations (ex, entering the time first)

Comment: A time will already be in the text box as there is a date picker. I just want to allow manual editing.

Comment: echo @sabof; it's impossible to validate the full regex on key up. if you keep removing everything onkeyup.. user will never be able to enter a full validated string

Comment: @CrayonViolent You can, if you really really want to. `/^a(b(c(d)?)?)?$/.test('abcd')`

Comment: @sabof well sure, but strictly speaking, that's a partial matching, as in "make sure that so far it's lookin' good" but it's not the same as "onkeyup, this must fully match"

Comment: Great point @CrayonViolent, this could actually be an issue. Using aelor's regex below, how could I check that the string the user has enter is "good so far"?

Comment: well.. before you get into that, you should really consider @sabof 's original point.. some people may not enter it in in the right order. Couple that with the fact that you say you don't care if it's a valid date to begin with.. why validate it at all? What would you really do with an Apr 45th type date to begin with?

Comment: There is also the "really really want" part. I personally don't. The result would be ~3 times longer than @aelor's regex. With readability and flexibility rapidly deteriorating.

Answer (score 1):

```
[A-Za-z]{3}\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}\sat\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}(am|pm)
```

will match your requirement exactly

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/rU8xT0\

using with js

```
var str = "Mar 1, 2014 at 2:00pm";
if( /[A-Za-z]{3}\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}\sat\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}(am|pm)/.test(str)){
  console.log("pass");
}
else{
  console.log("fail");
}
```

and this is exactly what you want, this will check for values which are not correct and highlight accordingly, I am using jquery to add and remove the class

```
$("#text").keyup(function () {
    if (/[A-Za-z]{3}\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}\sat\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}(am|pm)/.test($(this).val())) {
        $(this).removeClass('error');
        $(this).addClass('good');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('good');
        $(this).addClass('error');

    }
})
```

for OPs special requirement in js

```
var str = "Mar 1, 2014 at 2:00pmaur bahut sara kachra";
var res = str.replace(/([A-Za-z]{3}\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}\sat\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}(am|pm)).*/, '$1');
console.log(res);
```

fiddle demo here : **http://jsfiddle.net/kq65X/1/**

Comment: This looks great! I don't use regex often, how can use this with Javascript's .replace() function to remove all characters that do not fit this pattern? Thank you!

Comment: check my updated answer, ask for any other doubts if you have

Comment: As I said above, I actually need to remove all characters that do not fit the pattern—not just check if the input fits the pattern. Thank you!

Comment: ahh i got it now.. no problem , just a minor change in the regex will do it, i ll update the answer